# Is it possible to create an extension method using ReSharper?

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

I would like to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the Update method below (it doesn't exist) to create a new extension method.  Is there a way to do this in ReSharper?

```cs
List<FootyTeam> existingTeams = GetFootyTeams();
List<XmlTeam> newTeams = GetXmlTeams();

existingTeams.Update(xmlTeams);
```

*(note, I'm new to ReSharper)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm affraid this isn't possible at the moment ( even up to 9.1.3 ). There's the Static Method to Extension Method conversion, but not the refactoring you want.

> **Convert Static to Extension Method**
>
> This new refactoring converts a
>   static method to an extension method. For the conversion to be carried
>   out successfully, the static method must (1) have at least one
>   argument and (2) reside in a static class. The reverse functionality
>   is available with 'Convert Extension Method to Plain Static'.

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html